# Angular browseranimation slideup from bottom

Tags: css, angular, animation, types, css-animations

I am trying to create simple animation. Good is that it works but in reverse direction as I want.
What I want to do is to open div from bottom to top. And close div from top to bottom.

And this is my animation in angular

```
animations: [
    trigger('inOutAnimation', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ height: 0, opacity: 0,}),
        animate('1s linear ', style({ height: 318, opacity: 1 })),
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        style({ height: 318, opacity: 1 }),
        animate('1s linear', style({ height: 0, opacity: 0 })),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
```

Div I am animating has position absolute and his parent has position relative.
What can I do to reverse animation? I tried few things on internet but nothing seems to work like `animation-direction: reverse;`

Answer (score 0):

Better would be this approach. Define `state` and then your transitions like this:

```
 animations: [
trigger('inOutAnimation', [
  state('inState', style({ bottom: 0, opacity: 1 })),
  state('outState', style({ bottom: -100px, opacity: 0})),
  transition('inactive => active', [
    outState
    animate('1s linear', inState),
  ]),
  transition('active => inactive', [
    inState
    animate('1s linear', outState),
  ]),
  
]),
]
```

Then your `inOutAnimation` should change its value from `active` to `inactive` programmatically. Also I would suggest you to use `bottom` css instead of `height`.

Comment: Amazing ! Thank you

Comment: Thank you. I rewrite it how you meant it probably     `trigger('inOutAnimation', [
      state('inState', style({ bottom: 0, opacity: 1 })),
      state('outState', style({ bottom: -318, opacity: 0 })),
      transition('inState => outState', [animate('1s linear')]),
      transition('outState => inState', [animate('1s linear')]),
    ]),
  ],
})` because I was getting some errors. Its not exactly what I want. I want that divs to open from bottom like it should go from div bottom to div top. Now it starts under div and goes up.

Comment: Ok. You could simply use `height` property. Let me know if it works or explain me more.